# Launching juptyer notebook on paperspace?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-console

I have launched paperspace successfully multiple times before but after I accidentally logged out, it started to ask me for an access token, I entered the token that the virtual machine gave me but then it said that it's invalid so I restarted my computer and tried to log in again now when I go to localhost:8888/ it shows that the page cannot be found. I stopped my local jupyter notebook already can anyone help me figure out why? here is the message I receive

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by substituting my `localhost` to the IP address of the VM, I did not need to do this for the previous launches so I'm still kinda confused as to what happened but hope this helps